# Pinion gearbox + Gates belt drive - what are my options for 36-hole rear hubs?

Tags: single-speed, rear-wheel, gates

I currently have a touring bike with 36 spokes front and back, in the front with a SON 28, in the back with a Shimano Deore XT hub. I plan to switch my frame and I'm currently considering switching to a Pinion P 1.18 or C 1.12 gearbox with a Gates Carbon belt drive.

I thus researched what my options are for Pinion-specific single speed rear hubs, and Pinion itself only offers 32-hole rims. Also, the DT 240 are also 32-hole only. It currently looks as if my only option is a Deore XT or DT 540 Tandem hub with spacer rings to keep the rear sprocket in place. I've also found BMX-specific hubs, but I'm unsure if they are suitable for my needs, as I'm unsure if they have a freewheel ratchet mechanism.

Although I might change rims (26" -> 28"), it would end up silly having 36 spokes in the front and 32 spokes in the back. Do you know of any other options than standard hub + spacers? I should mention that I'd like to keep my 36-hole SON 28 and also not lace without using all holes, mainly because Roger Musson advises against that.

Comment: Is the tandem spacing required? BMX hubs are narrower and that will be a problem even if Gates has BMX style sprockets.

Comment: The number of spokes between front and rear wheel does not have to be the same.  I rode a road bike with 16 spoke rear and 32 spoke front wheel for several years.

Comment: No, they don't have to be. But the OP seems to be spending thousands to build his perfect bike and doesn't want any ugly hacks. I'd suggest Chris King, but I don't know about spacing requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! Chris King ISO single speed might actually be an option. I even saw it at one point, but was scared away by the price tag. While the bike overall is getting quite pricey, so far I was able to never invest too much into it, and it's been with me for the past 10 years. I've named it my "Theseus' Ship" - except for frame, handlebar and brakes, I don't think any piece is original. Now that I have to invest quite a bit, I should consider a more expensive hub, actually.

@Criggie, I'm aware that it's possible, but it's somewhat silly to have a sturdier front wheel, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope Pro 4 Trial/Singlespeed Hub is available in 36 hole configuration.

Here is a link to the product page:
https://www.hopetech.com/product/pro-4-trialssingle-speed-rear-hub/

You should be able to source them through your local bike dealer or via the internet. The are available for quick release and 12mm axles so you should be able to fit them to your new frame.

Comment: Brilliant, that's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Most frames I found accept 135mm QR, which Hope 36 hole rear hubs for single speed support. This goes well with my SON hub that's also QR. Finally, the price is more reasonable than Phil Wood, which is a pleasant surprise.

Comment: Perfect! Yeah the Hope stuff is priced pretty good considering the quality of their stuff. Also you should have no problems getting spares if something should brake and you can service them at home.